# Is `engine` a Python keyword?

Tags: python

I tried googling "Python engine keyword" or "python engine" but nothing useful is showing up.

In the codebase I am working with, I see the following:

```
  with engine(database_url).connect() as conn:
```

I did not `engine` imported, and I also did not see a `from [package_name] import *`.

This is in a section of the codebase that is doing sql queries.

Comment: `engine` could've been defined elsewhere in the file.

Comment: `engine` is not a Python keyword.  However, it is an object available from the `sqlalchemy` library.  [Docs linked here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html)

Comment: @12944qwerty I did not see it

Comment: You also mention that this was in the SQL part of the code. The first google search on "python SQL engine" reveals it's an object in sqlalchemy

Comment: Here you are a complete list of [Python keywords](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Comment: And SQL reserved words: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Answer (score 2):

It's not. You can use the `__module__` attribut to get the information about the parent module of this object.

```py
print(engine.__module__)
```

should print something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can simply google Python Keywords and won't find it listed on there. Also you can do a quick check, Python automatically warns you or gives you an error if you try to assign a keyword as a variable:

```
engine = 5
```

works fine.

Also in your case engine is a method. You can see that by the parenthesis around it.